# Data assignation with different variables

Tags: python

I need code that will allow me to set varying variables to a data set.
I do not know length of s
for example, s = adgrhds
I want 
    a = "a"
    b = "d"
    c = "g"

Comment: No, you don't need code to do this. A string is already iterable and accessible via  indexes, eg `s[1]` returns 'd'.

Comment: It is not really clear what do you want. A list is also a set of varying variables. Why dont yo use a list?

Answer (score 1):

I dont' know why you want to do this however, you might want to tweak `locals()` to set variables in the current scope:

```
>>> text = 'adgrhds'
>>> var_names = 'abcdefg'

>>> for i, c in enumerate(text):
...     locals().setdefault(var_names[i], c)

>>> print a
'a'
>>> print b
'd'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
a = string.letters[:26]
s = "adgrhds"
dic = {}
for i,j in zip(a,s):
    dic[i] = j
```

Comment: This code might help your need.

Answer (score 0):

Using dictionary this will overwrite if the same letter appear again

**Code:**

```
s = "adgrhds"    
dic={}    
for letter in s:
    dic[letter]=letter 
print dic
```

**Output:**

```
{'a': 'a', 'd': 'd', 'g': 'g', 'h': 'h', 'r': 'r', 's': 's'}
```

**Steps:**

Create a dictionary

Iterate over the string letter by letter

Add it to the dictionary

Comment: i need each letter to be assigned to a different variable.a = letter 1 b= letter 2 and so on.

Comment: @ChuahZiYang why do you need to assign it to a variable when you can use dictionary.You could do all the things you do using a variable in a dictionary

Comment: how is `a = 'a'` superior to `theDict['a'] = 'a'` for the problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: Im just a beginner at programming so i am not familiar with this command.@VigneshKalai

Comment: also i need the letters to be in order

Comment: So give @VigneshKalai excellent suggestion a try and see if it is a better way to solve the problem. Read more about dicts here https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html. Sorting the keys in a dict is trivial when you need the ordered step.

Comment: @jwpfox see this [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25904907#25904907)

Comment: So the people in that chat agree with both you and me that a `dict` is the obvious answer here. Good to have support but I don't think either of us doubted that before that chat (did we?). Not sure why you pointed me at the chat rather than the OP. Did you misunderstand my question to the OP about why they thought a pile of variables would be better than a `dict`? I was hoping the OP would look at your suggestion, ask themselves the question and answer it 'Ah ha - a pile of variables is NOT superior'.

Comment: @jwpfox I stated `some one [a mysterious person] :p` I too got confused.I just know `dict` is better but don't know why

Comment: I think we are wandering off the point. But nice work on your suggestion and clarifying why it is superior. :)